# Docker compose yaml fields?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I am totally new to Docker and yaml. I understand the formatting of yaml but quite confused about the different fields such ports, commands, environment etc that can be used in a docker-compose.yaml. Is there a yaml reference page that can help me understand the various fields that I can use in docker-compose.yaml file?

Thanks.

Comment: Top result when googling [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the reference documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/